# What does the -: following the last opt char do?

Tags: shell, getopts

I saw a getopts usage like this:

```
while getopts ":hv-:" optchar; do
...
done
```

What is the use of the last -:, with this placement, what the - and : have to do with the parsing behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:-:` at the end of the optstring `(":hv-:")` is used to handle long options (options starting with --). The placement of `-` and `:` after the `v` does not directly impact the behavior of the `v` option.

Here's the breakdown:

```
: at the beginning of the optstring suppresses error messages for invalid options.
h and v are valid short options.
The hyphen (-) after v indicates that v can take an optional argument.
The double hyphen (--) is used to indicate the end of options and to handle long options.
The last colon (:) at the end is a part of the getopts syntax and is associated with handling the long options.
```

The getopts command uses the `--` to distinguish between short and long options. When a long option is encountered, it is handled in the `--`) case inside the getopts loop. The colon `(:)` after the `-` in `:-:` is associated with long options that require arguments. For example, if you have a long option like `--input=file.txt`, the `:` after `-` allows you to specify that input requires an argument.

Here's a brief example:

```
while getopts ":hv-:" optchar; do
  case "${optchar}" in
    h)
      echo "Short option h detected."
      ;;
    v)
      echo "Short option v detected."
      ;;
    -)
      case "${OPTARG}" in
        h)
          echo "Long option --h detected."
          ;;
        v)
          echo "Long option --v detected."
          ;;
        *)
          echo "Invalid long option: --${OPTARG}"
          ;;
      esac
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: ${OPTARG}"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

In this example, short options `-h` and `-v` are handled, and long options `--h` and `--v` are also handled. The `:-:` in the optstring enables the handling of long options and their potential arguments.

Comment: Why is it before the last colon ? Does the last colon have an effect on the v option?

Comment: The placement of the last colon in the optstring (":hv-:") doesn't have a direct effect on the behavior of the v option. Each colon in the optstring serves a specific purpose, and their positions determine the behavior of the options.

Comment: `getopts` is really meant for single-character options only, and using `-` as the name of an option is a hack to enable long options, but it wouldn't make a lot of sense to have those *also* be single character options, just preceded by two dashes.

Comment: It seems like typo that you are saying `:-:` for 3 times not just `-:`, right? please update the answer.